# all remix read functions fail: call to X errored: [object Object]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, metamask

I'm facing an issue with Remix IDE and MetaMask Kovan testnet interplay. All contracts, even a basic ERC20.sol contract returns following error i.e: **"call to token.balanceOf errored: [object Object]"** I've tried switching back and forth between networks and resetting account under advanced settings in MetaMask - nothing works for me.

Comment: It is just Kovan? Do other networks fail? In that case I'd assume the provider has some issues.

Comment: just Kovan it seems

Comment: changing device and wifi settings didn't help either so must be the testnet provider